# Can Facebook's Graph API be used without using any SDK?

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, httprequest

Can the full functionality of the `Facebook Graph API` be used with HTTP Requests, rather than using any of the SDK's?  I've been able to use a `GET` requests to return public data; I've been able to use a `POST` request to make a post with an access token retrieved from Facebooks [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explore), but I'm not sure if `Login`, getting `Access Tokens` and determining whether a user has given `permissions`, is possible without using one of the SDK's?  I could spend the next 2 days using trial and error, and reading docs to try to find out, but I'd hate to waste a couple days going down a road to nowhere if someone can just give me the answer now.

Comment: I have since found how to trigger the Facebook login without using the SDK.  [Manually Invoke Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/)  Click on `Logging People In`.   `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}`  The `redirect-uri` needs to be able to retrieve a string appended to the URL.  Once the user logs in, Facebook appends a string to the URI with a `code` attached to the end.  I guess you can then exchange that code for an access token.

Comment: To prompt the user for a specific permission `&scope=name_of_permission` needs to be added to the end of the URL.  `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=Your_App_ID&redirect_uri=https://Your_App_URL&response_type=token&scope=publish_stream`  Once the user logs in, an access token with the expiration will be returned in the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely you can create application for Facebook without using any SDK..

SDK is just a software development kit (SDK or "devkit") it's typically a set of software development tools that allows for the creation of applications for a certain software package,

Facebook SDK made your work much easier because they give you ready made functions to call Facebook API
like PHP sdk ,C# sdk.. etc

If you want to create application without using it .. then you have to request Facebook Graph API directly ..

For e.g you need to get page information using JS SDK ..you need to pass only name/id  of the page
in JS SDK

```
FB.api('/cocacola', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

but if you want to go without SDK, then you need to call `http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola`
now you need to parse `JSON` then retrieve data based on the language you're working on